# How to get rid of this Mouse pointer on Android studio and get the editable one

Tags: android-studio

I am new to android development. The mouse pointer on the design page is as shown in the screenshot. I am not able to edit anything like increasing the height and width of the widget on this page. I might be able to do it in XML but I want it done here. 
I want a normal mouse pointer where I can edit the widgets.

I tried looking at some of the blogs but it didn't help.

[activity.xml - design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8o5k.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It worked after removing the cache files and restarting the android studio